# Getting the Article title for the Comment Crud

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii, object-relational-model

I created an Article and Comment Models and have CRUD on both. Its works perfectly. What I need now is to have the article.title field displayed in Comment Crud instead of the comment.articleid. How can I do that?

This is where I'm stuck. I don't know what to do next or if that's correct:

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'article'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Article', 'articleid')
    );
}
```

EDIT:

Here's my code admin.php view file:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'comment-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'commentid',
        'articleid',
        'content',
        'author',
        'email',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: on your relations function: which model is this code from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be something like this for the columns array:

```
'columns'=>array(
        'commentid',
        array(
            'name'=>'title',
            'value'=>'$data->article->title',
            'type'=>'text'
        ),
        'content',
        'author',
        'email',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: The variable shouldn't be quoted

Comment: In this construct, it does need to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create this relation in Comment model and it will fetch all matched records by joining article on basis of articleid

Then you can modify your views by replacing the values you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use comment->article->title instead of comment->articleid